# index out of range -- numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

what's wrong in this code? can't I simply *slice* the first column of `data` and assign it to X?

```
import numpy as np
data =np.array([[5.2, -1.5], [-4.1, 3], [-12.3, 55]])
print(data)
X = data[:,0]
print('shape of X ', X.shape)
print('X.shape[0] ',X.shape[0])
print('X.shape[1] ',X.shape[1])
```

it throws the following message:

```
shape of X  (3,)
X.shape[0]  3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shape.py", line 7, in <module>
    print('X.shape[1] ',X.shape[1])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: `len(X.shape)` should give you `1`, you can't do `X.shape[1]`/

Comment: As stated in print: ```shape of X  (3,)```, therefore it's completely expected behaviour.

Comment: `X = data[:,0]` results in `X` having one dimension less than `data`. So while `data` is two-dimensional, `X` is one-dimensional, and its `shape` tuple will only contain one element.

Comment: yes, indeed ```X = data[:,0] ``` results in 1D, but why? I understood the syntax means all rows (:), and column 0 ?

Comment: To improve the question, you could include what you expected the output to be, so that everyone helping you better knows what it is that you think is confusing.

Comment: I thought that ```X = data[:,0] ``` would produce a 2d array with dimensions nrows x 1. My next attempt has been ```X= data[:,0:1] ``` that does what I had in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define `X` as `data[:,0]`, you're creating a 1-dimensional array. Since your initial array, `data` is 2-dimensional, you can think of this as selecting only column-index-0-values from all rows. This means that the shape of `X` has only 1 element in it.

So `X.shape[0]` exists (it's `3`), but `X.shape[1]` doesn't exist, resulting in an IndexError.

Answer (score 1):

Note that *X* contains `array([  5.2,  -4.1, -12.3])`, so it is a **1-D**
array.

It can be seen also from the shape:

```
shape of X  (3,)
```

i.e.:

- the first **and only** dimension is *3*,
- there are no other dimensions.

So if you refer to `X.shape[1]` (a non-existing dimension), you get
`IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

No other way.

An alternative: If you want to have a **2-D** array, you can run:

```
X2 = data[:, [0]]
```

Then:

- `X2.shape` is `(3, 1)`,
- `X2.shape[0]` is `3`,
- `X2.shape[1]` is `1`.